# Properly encode url in urllib2 Python

Tags: python, urllib2

I have to make a series of requests to my localserver and check response. Basically I am trying to hit the right url by brute forcing. This is my code:

```
for i in range(48,126):
   test = chr(i)
   urln = '012a4' + test 
   url = {"tk" : urln}
   data = urllib.urlencode(url)
   print data
   request = urllib2.Request("http://127.0.0.1/brute.php", data)
   response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
   status_code = response.getcode()
```

I've to make request like: `http://127.0.0.1/brute.php?tk=some_val`
I am getting an error because the url is not properly encoding. I am internal server error 500 even when one of the url in series should give 200. manually giving that url confirms it. Also, what is the right way to skip 500/400 errors until I get a 200?

Comment: is `test = 'chr(i)'` what you want to do or `test = chr(i)` (quotes removed) ?

Answer (score 1):

When using `urllib2` you should always handle any exceptions that are raised as follows:

```
import urllib, urllib2

for i in range(0x012a40, 0x12a8e):
    url = {"tk" : '{:x}'.format(i)}
    data = urllib.urlencode(url)
    print data

    try:
        request = urllib2.Request("http://127.0.0.1/brute.php", data)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        status_code = response.getcode()
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print e.reason
```

This will display the following when the connection fails, and then continue to try the next connection:

```
[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

`e.reason` will give you the textual reason, and `e.errno` will give you the error code. So you could still stop if the error was something other than `10061` for example.

Lastly, you seem to be cycling through a range of numbers in hex format? You might find it easier to work directly with [`0x`](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html?highlight=hex#numbers-and-strings) formatting to build your strings.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will benefit from a `try/except` block:

```
 for i in range(48,126):
    test = 'chr(i)'
    new urln = '012a4' + test 
    url = {"tk" : urln}
    data = urllib.urlencode(url)
    print data
    request = urllib2.Request("http://127.0.0.1/brute.php", data)
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    except:
        status_code = response.getcode()**strong text**
    print status_code
```

You typically would also want to catch the error as well:

```
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

Or catch specific errors only, for example:

```
except ValueError:
    #do stuff
```

Though you wouldn't get a `ValueError` in your code.